# Why the flutter SDK hint the wrong property, Container should use Alignment type but hint the AlignmentGeometry?

Tags: flutter

When I create a `Container` the alignment property should use `Alignment` type to implement it:

```
  List<Widget> _getListWidgets() {
    List<Widget> list = new List();

    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i ++) {
      list.add(Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,  // there should use `Alignment` type.
      ));
    }

  }
```

but when I use <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Left Click</kbd> the property see the hint, there shows the `Type: AlignmentGeometry`.

So, why the flutter SDK hint is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance
Object->AlignmentGeometry->Alignment

Implementers
Alignment,AlignmentDirectional

so the AlignmentGeometry is base class for Alignment that allows for text-direction aware resolution

also you can notice there are different symbol beside the abstract class

[image]